# PHP cURL doesn’t send post data

Tags: javascript, php

I have this code:

```
$obj = $_POST["myData"];
     
$curl = curl_init();
$url = "whatever";
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $obj,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
      "Content-Type: application/json"
    ),
));
      
$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

The problem is that the curl does not send the request, unless I change the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $obj`, for the entire string which is:

```
{\"desSucursal\":\"423423\",
 \"indPlacas\":\"S\",
 \"horarios\":[],
 \"idConvenio\":{\"idConvenio\":\"1262\"},
 \"usrRegistro\":\"1645144\",
 \"usuarioJefe\":{\"idUsuario\":\"1645534\"}
}
```

But the var $obj, has the same data, cause $_POST["myData"] , is a variable post that it was sent from JS.

Does anybody know, what is the reason that if I put the entire string works, but if I put the variable which contains the same string doesn't work?

Comment: Q: So your question is: "curl_exec() doesn't send $obj in my POST command unless I assign $obj to CURL_POSTFIELDS"?  Uh... what did you *EXPECT*?!?

Comment: Or is it an issue with what comes back via AJAX in $_POST["myData"] is not the same as the hard coded string version. Which would then lead one to ask "Well why is it different"?

Comment: Do you want to send data as `key => value` pairs? Try `json_decode($_POST['myData']);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there are extra slashes in your `$_POST["myData"]` variable. You need to remove those:

```php
$obj = stripslashes($_POST["myData"]);
```

Note that you need to validate and sanitize any values you're getting from `$_POST`. You should not trust any incoming data as this is an open door for vulnerabilities.

Comment: I tried with str_replace and it didn't work, I'm going to try stripslashes